# Open access finance data set

Tags: data-request, finance, economics

I am looking for a finance data set. Particularly, I am interested in EuroStoxx50
or indices like S&P 500, and DAX data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Investing.com](https://www.investing.com/indices/eu-stoxx50-historical-data)

Get free historical data for EU Stoxx50. You'll find the closing price, open, high, low, change, and %change for the selected range of dates. The data can be viewed in daily, weekly or monthly time intervals

[S&P 500 stock data](https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/sandp500)

Historical stock data for all current S&P 500 companies

Stock market data can be interesting to analyze and as a further incentive, strong predictive models can have a large financial payoff. The amount of financial data on the web is seemingly endless. A large and well-structured dataset on a wide array of companies can be hard to come by. Here they provided a dataset with historical stock prices (last 5 years) for all companies currently found on the S&P 500 index.

The script used to acquire all of these .csv files can be found in this [GitHub repository](http://github.com/CNuge/kaggle_code)

Answer (score 1):

Quandl is likely to be your best bet. If you want price and volume data, you can look for indices (not all are available) or the continuous futures datasets (*e.g.* CHRIS/CME_ES1 for front-month S&P 500 futures).